# How can I dynamically change the value of a CSS property in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a class based component and `this.props.opacity` which define the opacity of a background and I have a class with the background with an opacity of 0 by default, I would like to change the opacity based on `this.props.opacity` which returns a number

For example:

```
this.props.opacity // is at 0 but it also changes when I'm on the page 

<div className={backgroundRed ? "background" : ""}> // is the JSX
```

The CSS:

```
.background {
  background: red;
  opacity: 1; // How do I make this value change based on this.props.opacity
}
```

FYI `this.props.opacity` has values from 0 to 1 and it looks like this: `0.073892020`

How can I dynamically change that by accessing the opacity value of my CSS class?

Comment: `<div className="background" style={{ opacity: this.props.opacity }} />`

Comment: @tomioion Sorry, I have a mistake. The JSX doesn't actually look like that

Comment: answers below are good. another option to consider: https://styled-components.com/

Comment: @KleoMagaret Ehh... I guess you need like this: `<div style={ backgroundRed ? { background: 'red', opacity: 1 } : { opacity: this.props.opacity }} />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly you can pass to html tag as an object style like this

```
<div className="background" 
     style={{ opacity: this.props.opacity }} 
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the CSS is being added to the page in the first place.

If, as it seems it is here, the CSS is entirely separate from the JavaScript (e.g. it is added to the page using a `<link>` element in the bootstrap HTML document), then the simplest approach is to forget about modifying the rule-set in the stylesheet and just use inline style:

```
const styleRules = { opacity: this.props.opacity };
return (<div className="background" style={styleRules} />);
```

There are a number of tools designed for associating CSS with components rather than pages, typically lumped under the banner heading of "CSS in JS". [This blog entry](https://blog.bitsrc.io/9-css-in-js-libraries-you-should-know-in-2018-25afb4025b9b) lists some popular ones.

I've used styled components in the past, and the approach there would be:

```
const BackgroundDiv = styled.div`
    background: red;
    opacity: ${props => props.opacity};
`;
```

and then:

```
<BackgroundDiv opacity={this.props.opacity} />
```

Comment: The CSS is in a different file and it is imported in my component, I don't think I can't just inline style because I don't know if some CSS properties such as `-ms-overflow-style` will work.

Comment: @KleoMagaret — Then  you just need to set the right property name. I guess `msOverflowStyle`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with similar requirements, recently needed something like this but the third party component needed a class name.  Styled components normally work well, but not in the scenario.  Came across the following blog entry [Create Custom Css](https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-create-css-custom-properties-that-dynamically-update-with-react-javascript/).  I normally do not interact with the document element like this in React so there might be some side effects, but did work well for what was needed.  I have included the two important pieces of code incase the link ever dies.

CSS:

```
.my-element { background-color: var(--my-favorite-color); }
```

In React/javascript

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--my-favorite-color','magenta');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do inline styling? Is there a reason not to do this?

```
<div className="background" style={{opacity: this.props.opacity}} /> // is the JSX
```